# error: package android.support.v4.view does not exist

Tags: android, react-native, android-support-library, android-appcompat, lottie

I am using `lottie` library for react native. I just installed it using `npm` and linked it using react native link but when I try to build it I get an error in lottie's class **error:**
`package android.support.v4.view does not exist`

These are my dependencies in app gradle

```
dependencies {
compile project(':lottie-react-native')
compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
compile project(':react-native-view-overflow')
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
// From node_modules
implementation "android.arch.work:work-runtime:$versions.work"
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.0'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.6@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.3'

}

 compileSdkVersion 28
buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.pois"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
    testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For newer versions of react-native support v4 is replaced with androidx ,Add this at end of your app level build.gradle If you had similar problem with other libraries you have to replace them like this

```
preBuild.doFirst { 
ant.replaceregexp(
    match:'import android.support.v4.view.', 
    replace:'import androidx.core.view.', 
    flags:'g', 
    byline:true
) { 
    fileset(
        dir: '../../node_modules/lottie-react-native/src/android/src/main/java/com/airbnb/android/react/lottie/', 
        includes: '*.java'
    ) 
}
```

Note that this happens if you enable androidX , If you do not want it disable it in .properties file

Answer (score 36):

Try doing this

```
npm i jetifier
npx jetify
```

Comment: This is correct, and make sure to have `android.enableJetifier=true
android.useAndroidX=true` in `gradle.properties`. source: https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-geolocation/issues/39

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar kind of issue
try to replace

```
compile project(':lottie-react-native')
compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
compile project(':react-native-view-overflow')
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
```

with

```
implementation project(':lottie-react-native')
implementation project(':react-native-vector-icons')
implementation project(':react-native-view-overflow')
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
```

also, update libraries to the latest versions,

Hope this will help

Comment: It's the same. I think the issue is with lottie only, I tried updating that using npm but no luck

Comment: try to delete libraries folder from .idea folder of project and then sync again